# Paperclip: Specify jpeg / jpg quality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is there an easy way to specify the jpeg quality of an image to be saved in the paperclip plug-in for rails 3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is pretty easy. Paperclip has an option called :convert_options which can be used for that purpose. It takes parameters that ImageMagick / Ghostscript can accept.

Here is an example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => ["100x100>", :jpg] },
                             :convert_options => { :thumb => "-quality 92" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @DanneManne's answer, if you want to convert the *original* image rather than add another style, simply define a style called `:original` and set `convert_options` for it like so:

```
has_attached_file :image,
  styles: { original:  {} },
  convert_options: { original:  "-quality 10" }
```